# Forcing reload of page using Framework7

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-framework-7

I am building a small webapp based on framework7 example split-view-panel which has a navigation bar on the left and if you click it loads a url to the right hand pane.

This is a php url.  However it seems that each time you click on the left, if the page has previously been loaded, it simply reloads from cache.  However I need it to call the php page again as I need to log time data on the php page for when it was clicked and loaded.

Is there a way I can force Framework7 to reload pages it has previoulsy loaded via ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Framework7 ignore certain URLs or even disable caching all together. Refer to the link below (section: Caching) for more details:

http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/init-app.html#.VnfJtPlVhHw

Comment: That's correct, I use cache: false to disable all cache and every time when I enter the page it got refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You must use pushState!
so where you define framework7 you must include this

```js
var myApp = Framework7({
    // Other Parameters if already there
    pushState: true
});
```

What this is doing is enabling a HTML5 feature called the History API which did not exist in HTML4 i think was the last version anyway people used to use a thing called root hashing (Just so you know this back story is off the top of my head but the code it what will make it work) which is basically what the PushState is in the History API just. Just so you know PushState in Framework7 will make your URL'S look like this `http://example.com/#!/profile.php?parameters4get=joe` but it doesn't affect how Framework7 handles your pages it just enabled the PHP to be reloaded each time.

Answer (score 0):

For Framework7 v4 use

```
var myApp = Framework7({
    view : {
        pushState: true
    }
});
```